# Custom Adapter to support RocketPant with Rails

Tags: batman.js, rocketpants, batman-rails

I am using `rocket_pants` gem to build backend API https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants

It have a specific format to output data:

```
{ 
    "response":[
        {"id":1,"title":"Object Title","description":"Object Description"},
        {"id":1,"title":"Object Title","description":"Object Description"} ],
    "count":2,
    "pagination": {
          "previous":null,
           "next":null,
           "current":1,
           "per_page":30,
           "count":2,
           "pages":1}
}
```

I am using `Batman.RailsStorage` to persist models. But actions like `MyApp.Model.get('all')` works fine on the backend but they actually do not parse and load model objects.

Can you guide me how to configure `StorageAdapter` or write new one to handle such kind of data format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try overriding the [`collectionJsonNamespace` method (defined on `Batman.RestStorage`)](https://github.com/batmanjs/batman/blob/master/modules/model_layer/storage_adapters/rest_storage.coffee#L99).

I see that it's [used after a `readAll` operation](https://github.com/batmanjs/batman/blob/master/modules/model_layer/storage_adapters/rest_storage.coffee#L242) to get records from the HTTP response.

For example:

```
class MyApp.RocketPantsStorage extends Batman.RailsStorage
   collectionJsonNamespace: -> "response"
```

Then in your model

```
#= require ../rocket_pants_storage
# the storage adapter must be available at load time
class MyApp.SomeModel 
   @persist MyApp.RocketPantsStorage
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

With the same approach mentioned in answer from @rmosolgo I build paginator as well.

```
class MyApp.RocketPantsPaginator extends Batman.ModelPaginator
  totalCountKey: "pagination.count"

  loadItemsForOffsetAndLimit: (offset, limit) ->
    params = @paramsForOffsetAndLimit(offset, limit)
    params[k] = v for k,v of @params
    @model.load params, (err, records, env) =>
      if err?
        @markAsFinishedLoading()
        @fire('error', err)
      else
        response = new Batman.Object(env.response)
        @set('totalCount', response.get(@totalCountKey));
        @updateCache(@offsetFromParams(params), @limitFromParams(params), records)
```